# Formatting currency from string session in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, visual-studio, session

Hello I am having difficulty with a web application. I am almost done but I am tripping up on this issue. So with this web application, there is another page that shows gets input from the user for a sales price and discount amount and then gets a total price from the sales price - discountamount. I finally got the second page (where this code is from) to grab the session string values but I need to format these correctly into currency. I copied the code from the first page in the commented out part to try to analyze it but I am at a loss and would appreciate the help as I am almost done.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Confirm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int salesPrice, discountAmount, totalPrice;
        UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
        if (Session["salesprice"] != null && Session["discountamount"] != null && Session["totalprice"] != null)
        {
            lblSalesPrice.Text = Session["salesprice"].ToString();

            lblDiscountAmount.Text = Session["discountamount"].ToString();
            lblTotalPrice.Text = Session["totalprice"].ToString();

            /*
            decimal salesPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesPrice.Text);
            decimal discountPercent = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDiscountPercent.Text) / 100;

            decimal discountAmount = salesPrice * discountPercent;
            decimal totalPrice = salesPrice - discountAmount;

            lblDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");
            lblTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");*/

        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "This function hasn't been implemented yet.";
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something because I don't quite understand what you are having an issue with or what the end goal is. Are you asking how to convert a string to currency or something entirely different?

Comment: That is what I am asking. I've got it working properly now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert the values in the session to currencies, you could to something like this:

```
if (Session["salesprice"] != null) 
    lblSalesPrice.Text = Convert.ToDouble(Session["salesprice"]).ToString("c");

if (Session["discountamount"] != null) 
    lblDiscountAmount.Text = Convert.ToDouble(Session["discountamount"]).ToString("c");

if (Session["totalprice"] != null)
    lblTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToDouble(Session["totalprice"]).ToString("c");
```

If you're absolutely sure the session values exist, you don't need to check for null.  You can read more about Standard Numeric Formatting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It helped so much. So I'm guessing what I was missing was the .ToString("c") and converting the string to double. To make sure I understand this correctly, the session values were saved to String "c" and I was calling them from the previous page, right? As well as the formatting from the previous page? I'm guessing this because of the currency shown when it brings it up from the session values.

Comment: The "c" stands for currency.  So you're taking a number (a double in this case) and rendering as a "currency".  This way .NET formats the number to the culture of your application.  It gets really interesting with different cultures, since .NET knows how to properly format for USD, Euros, Yen, etc..  As for how the values were stored in session, I can't tell that from the code you posted.  If my response correctly answered your question, please accept the answer.